# How to display javascript results in a div

Tags: javascript

Hi how do i display the javascript results in a div. the code is :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
COUNTER_START = 40
function tick () {
    if (document.getElementById ('counter').firstChild.data > 0) {
        document.getElementById ('counter').firstChild.data = document.getElementById ('counter').firstChild.data - 1
        setTimeout ('tick()', 1000)
    } else {
        document.getElementById ('counter').firstChild.data = 'done'
    }
}
if (document.getElementById) onload = function () {
    var t = document.createTextNode (COUNTER_START)
    var p = document.createElement ('P')
    p.appendChild (t)
    p.setAttribute ('id', 'counter')

    var body = document.getElementsByTagName ('BODY')[0]
    var firstChild = body.getElementsByTagName ('*')[0]

    body.insertBefore (p, firstChild)
    tick()
}
</script>
```

i want it to display the coundown counter in this div

```
<div id="counter"></div>
```

Thank you :D

Comment: ids have to be unique - you can't have a `div` and a `p` with id=counter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `innerHTML` for that:

```
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML = /* ... HTML string here ... */;
```

You can shorten that script a fair bit: [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iyibos/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iyibos/1/edit)

```
(function() {

    var elm = document.getElementById('counter');
    var counter = 40;

    tick();

    function tick() {
        elm.innerHTML = String(counter);
        --counter;
        if (counter >= 0) {
            setTimeout(tick, 1000); // <=== Note, a function ref, not a string
        }
        else {
            elm = undefined; // Release it as we don't need it anymore
        }
    }

})();
```

I wasn't sure what the stuff with the paragraph element was, so I didn't include that. If it was meant to add the `counter` element at the beginning of the `body` (as a `p`, not a `div`), then just change

```
var elm = document.getElementById('counter');
```

to

```
var elm = document.createElement('p');
document.body.insertBefore(elm, document.body.firstChild);
```

Doesn't even need the `id`. [Live Example](http://jsbin.com/iyibos/2) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/iyibos/2/edit)

Answer (score 0):

To change contents of div, use

```
document.getElementById("counter").innerHTML="something";
```